# Remove xml nodes with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I believe this style sheet should remove the COG elements with the CogIdentifier = 35806 but it is not. please assist.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>


  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--this should remove the cogs with the specified ID but it is not. bug-->
  <xsl:template match="//TRAN/DAY/COG[CogIdentifier/text()='35806']">
  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please show us the input XML so that we have a reproducible example (see: [mcve])

Comment: @Ober: is CogIdentifier is a child element or attribute

Comment: Perhaps there is a namespace in the input (but why make us guess?)

Answer (score -1):

You can use this

```
<xsl:template match="COG[CogIdentifier='35806']"/>
```

Comment: If `<xsl:template match="//TRAN/DAY/COG[CogIdentifier/text()='35806']">` does not work, why would your suggestion work?

Comment: As there is no input source provided than how can we assume that absolute path is correct or not.

Comment: How can you assume anything if you cannot reproduce the problem? Other suggestions have been made in the comments. You are simply shooting in the dark.